# Ubuntu 22.04, HDMI works, but display port fails

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, dell, 22.04, hdmi

There are three external monitors connecting to Dell latitude 7430 using a docking station with an onboard intel GPU.
The monitors can connect with HDMI cables, but fail when using the Display port.
The issue is that the dock station only supports one HDMI cable port, and I have to connect other monitors using the display ports.

Any idea why and how to fix this?

GPU INFO

```
sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 resolution=1920,1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:181 memory:6052000000-6052ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

Comment: The issue was resolved after installing the latest Dell driver. Maybe it helps others.

Comment: Hi there, seems we are having the same problem. How did you upgrade the drivers?

Comment: Hi, check here: https://www.dell.com/support/home/nl-nl/product-support/product/latitude-14-7430-2-in-1-laptop/drivers , I installed this package specifically: NR-152169-LS-1_DisplayLink_Ubuntu_5.6.1_Software

Comment: Solved mi issue. Thanks!